# Scanner only reading 1st token of a string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io, filereader, filewriter

New to the Java Language,

The following is my bit of code. However the whole string isn't written to the file. Only the First token is written to the file. Any Explanations ?

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FichierTexteWrite {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            System.out.println("Entrez le nom d'un fichier :");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String filename = in.next();
            FileWriter fwrite = new FileWriter(filename);
            System.out.println("Entrez une phrase a memoriser");
            fwrite.write(in.next());
            System.out.println("Writing on file complete ");
            fwrite.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried `nextLine()` method but that didn't seem to help. It forcefully wrote a blank caracter and terminated the program.

***---EDIT---***

I also tried :

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FichierTexteWrite {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            System.out.println("Entrez le nom d'un fichier :");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String filename = in.next();
            FileWriter fwrite = new FileWriter(filename);
            System.out.println("Entrez une phrase a memoriser");
            fwrite.write(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Writing on file complete ");
            fwrite.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If You don't believe please compile and run the program. It doesn't work. It doesn't let me input a string and goes straight into the next instructions which closes the stream and output File Written successfully.

Comment: What is really happening here is that you are only *reading* one token. `FileWriter` writes whatever you tell it to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `in.nextLine()` to get the whole line.

```
fwrite.write(in.nextLine());
```

Use nextLine() both times:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FichierTexteWrite {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            System.out.println("Entrez le nom d'un fichier :");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String filename = in.nextLine(); // *** note change
            FileWriter fwrite = new FileWriter(filename);
            System.out.println("Entrez une phrase a memoriser");
            fwrite.write(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Writing on file complete ");
            fwrite.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise your nextLine() call will read the end-of-line token for the first line, the one where you get the file name, and you don't want this.

Comment: hmmm interesting ! Why is this happening though ?

Comment: @hayonj: your first call to `in.next()` reads in a token, **but doesn't read the end-of-line token for that line**. When you next call `in.nextLine()` you read in that first line's (the line with the file name) end-of-line token and not the next line.

Comment: Worked Again ! Damn you're good ! Second time today you saved me :)

Comment: Found this link also that explains the issue... Sharing just in case other people fall into this very noobish trap.  http://rommelrico.com/java-scanner-not-working-difference-between-next-and-nextline/